# SwiftUI Button Action

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to coding. Can someone please explain to me why this code doesn't work?
I'm trying to open a sheet when a button is tapped.
The button is part of a Floating Action Button like in Gmail with multiple options.
This 'SecondaryButton' is the options the user sees when the FAB is active.

```
Button(action: {
    scanSheet.toggle()
  }, label: {
    //Scan Button
    SecondaryButton(open: $open, icon: "camera.viewfinder", label: "Scan", color: "Blue", offsetY: -90)
      .padding(.trailing, 40)
  })
    .sheet(isPresented: $scanSheet, content: {
      Text("Hello")
    })
```

Comment: How are you defining `scanSheet`? And if you always want the sheet to open I would use `scanSheet = true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your SecondaryButton has something to do with this. I tested it without just a Text as label and it works.

Did you try to load a Button into the Label?

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var scanSheet = false
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        scanSheet.toggle()
      }, label: {
        //Scan Button
        Text("Button")
          .padding(.trailing, 40)
      })
        .sheet(isPresented: $scanSheet, content: {
          Text("Hello")
        })
}
```

}